# Aggregating response from asynchronous publish subscribe channel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to call 4 web services asynchronously and aggregate the results to a single message.If one of the service takes more time to respond than the specified timeout(3sec) then the remaining responses which have arrived should be aggregated and the late coming messages should be discarded . For this i used the below snippet in spring configuration file

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatorInputChannel" group-timeout="3000"  send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" expire-groups-upon-completion="true"  output-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel"  ref="responseAggregator"   method="populateResponseHeader" >
</int:aggregator>
```

When one of the web service(lets say service4) call takes more time than the timeout value, then the thread for service4 keeps running in the background and the server send a 202 response. Any suggestions on how i should modify my aggregator to ignore the messages which arrive later than the timeout and get the response?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should take a look into the [Scatter-Gather](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) pattern.
Looks like it is fully sufficient for your use-case.

You should use `expire-groups-upon-timeout="false"`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="expire-groups-upon-timeout">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        Boolean flag specifying, if a group is completed due to timeout (reaper or
                        'group-timeout(-expression)'), whether the group should be removed.
                        When true, late arriving messages will form a new group. When false, they
                        will be discarded. Default is 'true' for an aggregator and 'false' for a
                        resequencer.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
                </xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Currently we are using spring integration version 4.0. So scatter-gather channel is not supported. Tried with expire-groups-upon-timeout="false". But still i'm facing the same issue because the threads created for asynchronous calls keeps running in background.Is there any way to stop the threads created by the task executor once the process is complete?

Comment: M-m-m, No. You can signal them though to `interrupt`, but that can happen only after the remote service client answer.

Comment: expire-groups-upon-timeout is not supported in spring integration 4.0. My bad i had tried by setting expire-groups-upon-completion="false". Is there any equivalent to expire-groups-upon-timeout in version 4.0

Comment: No, there is no, but you should be able to upgrade to the latest `4.3.9` pretty easily